# How to collapse data into the smallest number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which for each record there are possible multiple value pairs (e.g. email1 is paired with value1). Each record can have from 0 to 6 pairs like that. The dataframe looks somewhat like this:

```
id email1      value1     email2     value2     email3      value3 ...
1  x@test.com  123        NaN        NaN        NaN         NaN
2  NaN         NaN        y@test.com 456        NaN         NaN
3  z@test.com  789        NaN        NaN        a@test.com  012
...
```

I want to shift the value pairs left, reduce the number of unnecessary columns and transform the above example into something like this:

```
id email1      value1     email2      value2     
1  x@test.com  123        NaN         NaN        
2  y@test.com  456        NaN         NaN
3  z@test.com  789        a@test.com  012        
...
```

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Is it fixed that if the email is NaN then the corrosponding value is also NaN?

Comment: In my case - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it fixed that if the email is NaN then its corrosponding value is also NaN then:

use Transpose then `agg()` then again transpose and finally drop columns that has NaN's:

```
df=df.T.agg(sorted,key=pd.isnull).T.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

OR

```
df=(pd.DataFrame(df.agg(sorted,key=pd.isnull,axis=1).tolist(),columns=df.columns)
      .dropna(axis=1,how='all'))
```

output of `df`:

```
    id  email1      value1  email2      value2
0   1   x@test.com  123.0   NaN         NaN
1   2   y@test.com  456.0   NaN         NaN
2   3   z@test.com  789.0   a@test.com  12.0
```